# Why is my menu not inline in cellphones but works right in laptops

Tags: css

On my page, http://jerrittpace.com/aboutme.html, the menu bar is not displaying inline on cellphones like the other pages on the site, and I cannot figure out what the problem is. Thanks for your help!

i've tried to change the css to inline for all the div containers surrounding the menu bar, but nothing is working.

```
<div class="left">
          <div class="LINKS">
            <p> <a href="home.html">HOME</a></p>
            <p><a href="aboutme.html">ABOUT ME</a></p>
            <p><a href="gallery.html">GALLERY</a></p>
            <p><a href="contactme.html">CONTACT ME</a></p>
          </div>
    </div>
```

then the css is

```
.LINKS {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0;
    background-position: 16% 2%;
    bottom: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    font-size: xx-large;
    display: inline;
}
```

I want the menu bar to be inline when displayed on a cellphone, like the other pages on the site.

Comment: If you can set the font-size to small using media queries, you can see it inline. Otherwise, use a hamburger menu.

Answer (score 1):

if you still need a inline menu try scrolling navigation for mobile.

example:
**HTML**

```
<ul class='nav'>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul.nav {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;

  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;

  font-size: 0; /* to remove extra line space of inline-block */

}
ul.nav li {
  padding: 12px 16px 13px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
ul.nav li a{
  color: #64cce3;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul.nav li:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(114, 124, 135, 0.2);
}
ul.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
ul.nav::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

[Live Example](https://codepen.io/ramshid/pen/dxXVLq)